# Created a new web application

Tags: web-application, iis

[image]

I Created a web application and it is showing the error the page cant be displayed.

I also selected SSL while creating the webapp.

Comment: Are the web services and app pool started in IIS?

Comment: Have you created site collection after creating web application?

Comment: Yes i have created the site collection and i have seen the app pools started and services are up and running

Comment: if you observe the screenshot test is the name of site collection